# For Loop Background Job Control

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, jobs

When a for loop is running inside a bash script, how can I put a job in the background to advance the loop once to use more than one processor from another terminal? I know the process IDs of the loop and of the current job from ps -f. Is there a way to use them to put the current job in the background when none of them show up as jobs in a separate terminal?

Comment: A shell only has job control of the processes that are started by that shell. You can put processes in the background in the script by ending with `&`, but since they're not children of the interactive shell, it won't have control over them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an & to the end of the command. That "detaches" the command and let the script running and not waiting until the command finished. 
If you want to make the process later accessible you can use `screen` and start an detached screen. Then you or the script can simply reconnect to the detached process by entering `screen -r`